# I have an issue with the mint function in the smart contract

Tags: solidity, smart-contract-wallets, mint

This is my mint function, "not enough eth sent" error shows up on minting even though there is enough eth in the wallet.

mint price is: 0.02 ether
and there is much more in the rinkeby test net in my wallet.

```
function mint(uint256 quantity_) external payable {
        require(isPublicMintEnabled, "mint is not active");
        require(totalSupply() + quantity_ < maxSupply, "exceeded max sup");
        require(
            _numberMinted(msg.sender) + quantity_ <= maxPerWallet,
            "can not mint this many"
        );
        require(msg.value >= mintPrice * quantity_,"not enought eth sent");
        _safeMint(msg.sender, quantity_);
    }
```

I tried to change the require statement to

```
require(msg.value == 0 ether);
```

and it worked just fine, so my guess is that msg.value is not sending any ether at all. I have been trying to know how to get the mint price to be sent from the msg.sender but I have reached a dead end.
Hope someone to help me if you faced a problem like this.

This is the code when I try to call the function from a minting page

```
async function handleMint() {
        if (window.ethereum) {
            const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
            const signer = provider.getSigner();
            const contract = new ethers.Contract(
                BLFRNFTADDRESS,
                BLFRNFT.abi,
                signer
            );
            try {
                    const response = await contract.mint(BigNumber.from(mintAmount), {
                    value: ethers.utils.parseEther((0.02 * mintAmount).toString()),
                });
                console.log("response: ", response);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log("error: ", err)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: We need to see how are u calling this function, because u are not sending ether with the tx correctly. U need to give the amount while sending the tx because it does not calculate automatically. So your error is not in solidity code

Comment: when I call it on Remix I need to send the price amount in wei in the value field then it works. but from a minting page does not work.

Comment: Calculate the value outside the try catch block and maybe print it to make sure that you are giving it correctly

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: const valueToSend = ethers.utils…… and then console.log(valueToSend) and then use the valueToSend in the transaction